# Does CakePHP have a specific way to redirect to a view of a record just added?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I'm wondering if CakePHP 1.3 has a convention for how you should find the last row added, so that you can redirect to a view of that record.

At the minute the user would create a new bill by going to "/bills/add" and filling in the form. On completion I'd like to send them to "/bills/view/[id of the row they just added]"

I know I can do this using "mysql_insert_id()" but I'd like to think CakePHP has a neater way of doing it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After saving the new record, you can redirect with:

```
if ($this->YourModel->save($data)) {
    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'view', $this->YourModel->id));
}
```

After calling save, ->id is populated with the new insert id.

[Manual](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1031/Saving-Your-Data)

Comment: My brain isn't working today, I even read the page you linked to earlier and didn't pick up on that. Thanks a lot for the help, worked perfectly!